# Unable to install AppFabric (Error: Custom file location is not accessible)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, prerequisites

I am trying to do offline installation of Windows AppFabric on Windows Server 2012 using prerequisites installer as below but getting error.

**Command**

```
/AppFabric:C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64
```

**Error**

```
Error: Custom file location is not accessible
```

I have confirmed that the file exists at the above location and that I am local administrator of that machine.

Here's some background on what I am doing. This machine doesn't have internet access as I tried to run prerequisites installer but it won't install.

So I downloaded all softwares required one by one and placed them in following location:

```
C:\Users\myuser\Downloads
```

After that I installed them by double clicking on the exes. Then I tried to install SharePoint and got error about AppFabric not installed or not properly not configured (something to that effect). Upon searching I came to know that you shouldn't install those softwares like that and instead should have used prerequisites installer to install them one by one as it also configures them.

Anyway I uninstalled AppFabric (which is another story as I had to try like 3, 4 times) and now I am trying to install it using prerequisites installer command line option but getting error.

Please help.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer instead :)

Comment: That is right!!
rename the end of the file from 64-enu to 65-enu
impossible how they didn t find out before production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the files to a "non-user-specific" place, like directly under c:\installation or so. It could be a problem of

> Access Denied

Comment: It turns out the error was not due to some access problem but because I didn't write file name extension in the end ".exe". So basically it should be like this   /AppFabric:C:\Users\myuser\Downloads\WindowsServerAppFabricSetup_x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have downloaded the installer script from the Net, after removing one by one arguments from the script I found that there is an unknown character in AppFabric file name! typing the file name (including file extension) again and running the script solved the issue!